# Comparision problems with PHP when comparing strings with large numbers

Tags: php, joomla, php-5.3

I have a problem with PHP. I've built an application which connects to an Oracle DB, fetch some data, and sometimes make some comparisions.

The problems is that the Oracle data uses really large integer Ids (21 characters long). I try to use this Ids as strings, but when I try to compare this strings I get different results, depending if I'm working on the production server (Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.3.10) or on the development machine (Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP 5.5.9).

This is one of the functions that doesn't work correctly:

```
public function isSomeUser($userId) {
    $blacklist = array(
        '102300000000000000693',
        '102300000000000001194',
        '102300000000000001593',
        '102300000000000001994',
        '102300000000000001996',
        '102300000000000002395',
        '102300000000000001998',
        '102300000000000002496',
        '102300000000000002097',
        '102300000000000002490',
        '102300000000000002493',
    );

    return (in_array($userId, $blacklist));
}
```

On the dev machine, if I call isSomeUser('102300000000000009999'), the returned value is false (the element doesn't exist in the array), but on the production machine, the returned value is always true. I can fix this behavior adding a last parameter to the in_array call with the value TRUE.

The problem is with Joomla 3.3.6. I've built some modules that use this IDs to build select fields (comboboxes). In the dev machine, this select fields are built correctly, but on the production server the **selected="selected"** parameter is added to ALL the options.

I know I can hack the core Joomla files to correct this behavior (maybe, when creating the select fields, instead of use the == operator it should be changed to a === operator), but if I change this files Joomla updates will be a problem...

So, what can I do? If I update to PHP 5.4, will this "problem" be corrected? Should I modify the core Joomla files? Any other idea?

Comment: Your production OS is 32-bit, and php integers are platform-dependent. The only reliable option is to upgrade to a 64-bit OS.

Comment: Regardless of whether it fixes your problem you should upgrade PHP on your production server. 5.3 is unsupported and there have been, by my (rough) count, 22 CVE fixes just between versions 5.3.10 and 5.3.29.

Comment: @georg: No, the dev machine (a virtual machine) is 32-bit, and the production server is 64-bit...

Comment: @timclutton: I'll ask the system administrator if it's possible to upgrade PHP. But is there any workaround to fix my issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all, so I assume it must be a difference in the data returned from Oracle. Are you using the same data source in dev and prod? Have you manually verified the value really isn't in the array?

Comment: Validation code: http://codepad.org/3b3FgKO2
You can try running this in both your environments and see what the result is.  This runs correctly for me on `Windows PHP 5.5.19 32bit`, `linux PHP 5.3.29 64bit`, and `linux PHP 5.2.5 64bit`.

Comment: @timclutton: Yes, I've verified that the data is correct, using the typical die(var_dump($userId) . var_dump($blacklist)). And yes, dev and prod are using the same oracle datasource. Now I'll try your validation code.

Comment: @timclutton If modified the validation code to add real production IDs: http://codepad.org/HgkTz0TX. The results on production are (F, F, T, T, T, T, F, F, F, F, T, F, F, F), and the results on dev are (F, F, F, T, T, T, F, F, F, F, T, F, F, F)

Answer (score 1):

Testing with these inputs (a value that doesn't exist in `$blacklist`)...

```
isSomeUser('100500000000000000683'); // should be false.
isSomeUser(100500000000000000683); // should be false.
```

...seems to show a bug in older versions of PHP (*or in 64bit versions*).

Results:

```
a = win 5.5.19 32bit
b = win 5.4.24 32bit
c = lin 5.2.5 64bit
d = lin 5.3.29 64bit
e = lin 5.5.9 32bit  (OP development box)
f = lin 5.3.10 64bit (OP production box)

 expected | a | b | c | d | e | f
----------|---|---|---|---|---|---
 f        | f | f | t | t | f | t
 f        | t | t | t | t | t | t
```

Since [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php), even on a 64bit installation, is less than the input value it is converted to a `float` and the second test fails for every version. This is understandably erratic behaviour.

But there is clearly something wrong with the results of `c, d, and f` on the first test where `true` is returned instead of the expected `false` *for a loose type string comparison*.

The failing versions are all < 5.4 *and* 64bit.  As [I mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288960/comparision-problems-with-php-when-comparing-strings-with-large-numbers#comment43046469_27288960), you should anyway upgrade the production server to at least the latest 5.4. If the problem persists then I would say this is a bug in 64bit versions of PHP and should be [reported](https://bugs.php.net/) as such.

Comment: @mHouses Any feedback on this?